# Matplotlib & LaTeX

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, latex

I use MikTeX and try to obtain LaTeX fonts in my matplotlib plots.

However, using the [demo](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/usetex_demo.html) code, Jyputer Notebook says that there is no latex,

```
Failed to process string with tex because latex could not be found
```

I try to add into PATH the path to latex.exe, dvipng.exe and ghostscript. Unfortunately, it still does not work. What I do wrong?

If I evaluate the following

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
plt.plot(np.sin(np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)),label=r"$\mathcal{M}=2$")
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.legend()
```

it returns me the next picture,

[image]

So, I see that `\mathcal{}` command works perfectly, whereas the fonts are not "latex".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `plt.rc('text', usetex=True)`.

Comment: As I have mentioned, it does not work. I have added all the variables into the PATH (latex.exe, dvipng.exe & ghostscipt) but matplotlib says that latex could not be found

Comment: @ArtemAlexandrov Did you try the different troubleshooting steps? Probably none of them will work for you, since it is not even finding latex. For the PATH variable: make sure to add only the path to the directory, without the executable name.

Comment: I will check my PATH variable, thx. Unfortunately, I have not find useful troubleshooting steps in matplotlib documentation. My guess that it can be related to MikTeX but I am not sure

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the link to the troubleshooting: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/text/usetex.html#troubleshooting